# Computing a Tensor Algebra

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

Let $n_i \in \mathbb{N}$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$ and let $T(M)$ denote the tensor algebra of a graded $R$-module $M$. I am trying to show there exists an isomorphism as follows:
$$
T\left( \bigoplus_{i=1}^k \tilde{H}_*(S^{n_i}) \right) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_k],
$$
where the degree of $x_i$ is $|x_i|=n_i$. Put differently, I want to show that the tensor algebra spanned by reduced homology groups of spheres is the same as the free associative algebra generated by $k$ elements of degrees $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ respectively.

Morally, this seems to work out, since we get one generator from each reduced homology group, hence $k$ many in total, and then we simply take the tensor algebra on these elements. So this should essentially be the free associative algebra on $k$ generators, i.e. precisely the right-hand side.

Is this argument sufficiently rigorous, or do we need to be more careful? Thanks for any help or hints!

Comment: Your notation of the right hand side is usually used for polynomials... which might be confusing. How do you define the tensor algebra ? The universal property should answer the question.

Comment: @Jonas I edited my question to be more precise: by $T(M)$ for a graded $R$-module $M$ I mean $\bigoplus_{n \geq 0} M^{\otimes n}$, where we understand $M^{\otimes0} = R$. Thanks for the hint about the universal property, I'll give it a try! By the way, what is the standard notation for the right-hand side? You're right, my notation is a bit confusing.